# Using Streams to filter objects

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a way to use streams to find an Enum based on its value?

```
Enum SomeEnum{
Dell("dell"),
IBM("ibm"),
Lenovo("lenovo")
}

public SomeEnum getEnumBased on value(String inputvalue)
{
SomeEnum someEnum = null;

for(Enum enumeration: someEnum)
 {
 if(enumeration.value().equals(inputvalue)
   {
     someEnum = enumeration;
   }
 }
return someEnum;
}
```

can this be done with streams?

Comment: Why not just use its name?

Comment: Simple answer is: yes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the answers. Much appreciated :)